# How to access child element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Im familiar with accessing parent windows like this:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("ad_nr")
```

But what if I want to access a child window from a parent? (iframe for example) and then set a hidden input in there to some value created in the parent window, how is this done?

Probably easy but I have missed it, so Im asking you guys!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `window.frames` collection.

For example:

```
window.frames[index].document.getElementById('myInputName').value = someValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
frames["FRAME_NAME_HERE"].document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = "Whatever";
```

Note:  the document in the iframe *must* reside on the same domain as the parent.  There is no getting around this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window.frames array to access child frames.
Example:

```
window.frames[0].document.getElementById('myElement')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access the frames collection and use the document in the usual way. For example:

```
window.frames['loader_frame'].document.getElementById("ad_nr")
```